# Twitter API - GET users/suggestions/:slug/members returns same persons on every call

Tags: laravel, twitter

I'm trying to get unfollowed suggested members but Twitter API returns same persons in every call, even if user follow them.

I'm using laravel and I'm not directly use api. I'm using `thujohn/twitter` package for that.. But I check it vendor files, everything seems fine..

**In Controller**

```
$suggested_members = Twitter::getSuggestedsMembers('politics');
```

What is my mistake in here ? I tried to pass `screen_name`, or my `user_id` but still same

Comment: Judging by [Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-suggestions-slug-members) documentation, it just returns suggested members for the topic. Nowhere does it say that it returns ones you don't follow. So I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: I see.. Then what is the point of this ? it's meanless